# ImportError: cannot import name 'evaluate' ( from surprise import evaluate )

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, anaconda, recommendation-engine

```
from surprise import Reader, Dataset, SVD
from surprise import evaluate
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-6d771df269b8> in <module>()
----> 1 from surprise import evaluate

ImportError: cannot import name 'evaluate'
```

The first line, from surprise import Reader, Dataset, SVD works fine. 
Just that, it's not able to import the evaluate from the surprise package.

I have installed the scikit-surprise using conda. 
I think it was installed successfully.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the documentation, the `evaluate()` method was [deprecated in version 1.0.5](https://github.com/NicolasHug/Surprise/blob/83971c3e61b3d0f1dbd13b17e990917811ca4b70/CHANGELOG.md#version-105) (functionally replaced by [`model_selection.cross_validate()`](https://surprise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/model_selection.html#cross-validation)) and was [removed in version 1.1.0](https://github.com/NicolasHug/Surprise/blob/83971c3e61b3d0f1dbd13b17e990917811ca4b70/CHANGELOG.md#version-110), which is likely what you have installed.

Answer (score 12):

As of January 2020, do something like the following instead...

```
from surprise import SVD
from surprise import Dataset
from surprise.model_selection import cross_validate

# Load the dataset (download it if needed)
data = Dataset.load_builtin('ml-100k')

# Use the famous SVD algorithm
algo = SVD()

# Run 5-fold cross-validation and then print results
cross_validate(algo, data, measures=['RMSE', 'MAE'], cv=5, verbose=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @merv, `evaluate()` method is deprecated in version 1.0.5. This is a working example tested with `scikit-surprise==1.1.1`:

```
import pandas as pd
from surprise import SVD, Reader
from surprise import Dataset
from surprise.model_selection import cross_validate

reader = Reader()
csv = pd.read_csv('yourdata.csv')

# Loading local dataset
data = Dataset.load_from_df(csv, reader)

# Use SVD algorithm or other models
model = SVD()

# cross-validation with no. of kfold=5 (can be changed per your need)
cross_validate(model, data, measures=['rmse', 'mae'], cv=5)
```

Train the model

```
data_train = data.build_full_trainset()
model.fit(data_train)
```

Predict

```
model.predict(uid=<e.g. 1>, iid=<e.g. 2>)
```

You can read the [documentation](https://surprise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html) for more details.